# Result of a prediction in CNN

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, prediction, conv-neural-network

I am working on the following link 
https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8 
How do I know that “one” in “result[0][0]” is the prediction of a “dog” and not a cat?

Comment: check the dataset. you will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the article uses the `ImageDataGenerator` class and the `flow_from_directory()` function to load and augment the images. Checking the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) you can find information about one of the arguments called `classes`:

> Optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']).
>   Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be
>   automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under
>   directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different
>   class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label
>   indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping
>   from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute
>   class_indices.

Based on that information I suspect that 'cat' refers to a 0 while 'dog' refers to a 1. To make sure you can check the class dictionary:

```
print(train_datagen.class_indices)
```